# Scala doesn't create any overloaded constructors for default values

Tags: java, scala, default-value

I'm working in Scala and considering a problem with default values in Scala constructors.

For example a Scala class with a default value:

```
class SomeAClass(someParam: SomeBBaseClass = new SomeImpOfBBaseClass()) { ... }
```

My problem is the compatibility to Java. I expexted there would be created an overloaded constructor like SomeAClass() and SomeAClass(SomeBBaseClass someParam), but there is only the last one, so that the default value is effectively meaningless.

I could create Auxiliary Constructors by myself to keep compatible with Java, but I hope there is an another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any solution other than custom constructors. You must create overloaded constructors manually if you need them. You could try doing something with macros, but I'm not sure if it is possible.

In fact, this has a reason. What if you have multiple default parameters? Which overloads should be generated then?

Answer (score 0):

In Scala constructor overloading is done by using Auxiliary constructor.

**Auxiliary Constructor**

In Java one can overload the constructors to provide different constructors accepting different parameters. On similar lines Scala classes can declare Auxiliary constructors which are overloaded forms of the Primary Constructor. The auxiliary constructors are named as this. Lets see an example:

```
class Employee(val firstName:String, val lastName:String){
var age:Int = 0

  //Auxiliary Constructor
 def this(firstName:String, lastName: String, age:Int){
this(firstName,lastName)
 this.age = age

  }
override def toString():String = {
"First Name: "+firstName+" Last Name: "+lastName
}
}
```